# Change a certain occurrence of a letter in a string

Tags: java, string

Say I have a string, and I want to change the second "a" in that string to an "e".

```
    String elephant = "elaphant";
```

I tried using String.replace(), but that replaces all the a's in the string, returning "elephent".

```
    elephant.replace("a", "e");
```

Is there any loop or method I can use to accomplish this? Thank you all.

Comment: It could be done with regular expression. but I don't know how, I am not so good in regex.

Comment: @awkwardgiraffe is it always second a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the index of the first occurrence of a letter.

Try using the indexOf method.

```
int myIndex = elephant.indexOf('a');
```

Once you have the index, use StringBuilder to replace the value. Something like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(elephant);
sb[index] = myIndex;
elephant = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: This comment did answer my question, but what if I want to get the index of the second or third occurrence? Or a sequence of letters?

Comment: @awkwardgiraffe You can try using the first occurrence of 'a' as the starting index so it doesn't get included when you're interested in getting the second value. You already have the first index stored in the myIndex variable so you do something like: int mySecondIndex = elephant.indexOf("a", myFirstIndex + 1); Of course, if you wanted to get the third, you could follow the same approach and use the second as the starting point and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert it to a char array, switch out the desired letter, then convert it back to String?

```
String elephant = "elaphant";


int index = -1;
int count = 0;  

while(count < 2) {
    index = elephant.indexOf("a", index+1); 
    count++;
}
if(index >= 0 && index < elephant.length()) {
    char[] tmp = elephant.toCharArray();
    tmp[index] = "e";
    elephant = new String(tmp);
}
```

Or if you prefer StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder sbTemp = new StringBuilder(elephant);
sbTmp = sbTmp.replace(index, index+1, "e");
elephant = sbTmp.toString();
```

Comment: your second approach gives string out of boundary issue. for your fist approach you can not assign String to char array

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
    String elephant = "elaphant";
    //convert the string to array of string
    String[] sp = elephant.split("");
    int countA = 0;
    boolean seenTwice = false;
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
        //count number of times that a has been seen
        if (sp[i].equals("a")) {
            countA++;
        }

        // if a has been seen twice and flag seenTwice has not been see
        if (countA == 2 && !seenTwice) {
            result += "e";
            seenTwice = true;
        } else {
            result += sp[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
elaphent
```

Comment: The output I'm looking for is "elephant" not "elaphent".

Comment: @awkwardgiraffe you said "I want to change the second "a" in that string to an "e".: so I did what you want. if you want to change the first a , it is eaiser and I can update my answer

Comment: I meant to say change the second "e" to an "a". No worries though, I already got my answer.